# Contradiction between results of ERS point optimal and ADF Uni Root Tests

Tags: time-series, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a hypothetical time series data which is derived from following . equation

y =0.10 + 0.75 Trend+  1.00 −1_ + ε

When I apply standard ADF procedure to data, I see that y has a unit root while log(y) is stationaty. However, when I apply ERS Point Optimal Unit Root Test, I am receiving an absurd 51,465,638 value as test statistics and I see that data is stationary even without making log transformation.

Do I skipped an important assumption for ERS test or not?